# String getting cut when converted from php to html

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following string.

```
$onclick= " return false;";
```

And I'm trying to insert it in my HTML code like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="grabados" name="grabados[]" value="no" onclick="return false;">
```

with this code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="grabados" name="grabados[]" value="{{ (is_null($partida['grabado'])  ? 'no' : 'si') }}" {{ (is_null($partida['grabado'])  ? '' : ' checked') }} {{ $partida['tipo'] == "otro" ? "onClick = ".$onclick : ""}}>
```

instead I'm getting this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="grabados" name="grabados[]" value="no" onclick="return" false;>
```

When it gets to the space the string is cut

I have tried escape sequences, HTML functions, string functions, everything with no  results.

A little help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not getting that, that's what shows up in the inspector, aka what the browser has interpreted. Your problem is that you're not delimiting the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get closed as a typo shortly, as you've forgotten to delimit the attribute value. In the meantime, here's an example of how to do this while still having readable code:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="grabados"
    name="grabados[]"

@if (is_null($partida['grabado']))
    value="no"
@else
    value="si"
    checked="checked"
@endif

@if ($partida['tipo'] === "otro")
    onClick="{{ $onclick }}"
@endif
/>
```

Also note, if you're creating multiple of these, you are repeating your `id` attribute, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<input type="checkbox" id="grabados" name="grabados[]" value="{{ (is_null($partida['grabado'])  ? 'no' : 'si') }}" {{ (is_null($partida['grabado'])  ? '' : ' checked') }} {{ $partida['tipo'] == 'otro' ? "onClick = '".$onclick."'" : ""}}>
```

Comment: the results were <input type="checkbox" id="grabados" name="grabados[]" value="no" onclick="'" return="" false;&#039;=""> Thanks a lot for your help